# Assigning value to local variable then accessing the global variable in python

Tags: python

I just started with python. I came across with the keyword `global` to get the value of global variable.

Lets say I have following code

```
str="I'm Global"

def func():
   '''
   str="Gives error" # can't create a local variable with same name as of global variable
   '''
   global str
   print "Global:: " + str
   str="I'm Local" # I don't want to override the global value
   print "Local:: " + str 
   '''
   print "Want to print Global value but can't because it's got overriden" + str
   '''

func()
```

with other language say C++ we can have option whether to use local or global variable while doing i/o operation using **(:: scope resolution operator)** but I didn't find anything like this.

So is there any option in python s that I can create a local variable (yes having the same name as of global variable) with same options like C++ for resolving the scope (global seems not to help in this issue)

Comment: That commented out code would *not* give an error. It's perfectly legal to create a local variable with the same name as a global one.

Comment: As Martjin Pieters says in his answer - use names that don't conflict. Try to use names that are as explicit as possible, if you know from the name of the variable that is global then naming conflicts should arise less often.

Comment: @vaultah What if I want the value at that time of execution and then i need to change the local variable value then?

Comment: ["Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"](https://www.python.org/doc/humor/#the-zen-of-python) -- Tim Peters

Comment: Python searches the global scope if the variable can not be found in local scope, hence your `global` statement is useless.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah it will give a warning. _SyntaxWarning: name 'str' is assigned to before global declaration_

Comment: I've added something that possibly looks like what you're trying to do.  But it's more of a demonstration why this is not a good idea, than a demonstration ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do what you want, not like that. Variables are either always local, or they are instead global throughout the whole scope.

You can access global names through the [`globals()` dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) too:

```
def func():
    print "Global:: " + globals()['str']
    str = "I'm Local"
    print "Local:: " + str
```

Doing so is bad practice at any rate. Just use names that don't conflict.

You also should not use the name `str` for variables, you are masking the [built-in type object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: @Martinj Pieters good catch of str. But what if in some business requirements wants me to do this. I can do this by using other language like Java and C++. You mean python doesn't have anything for this?

Comment: @dnup1092: there is no business requirement to use specific local names. That's just nonsense.

Comment: @dnup1092: local names are the 'private' business of a function implementation. It is **always** possible to use a different name.

Comment: if this is the case then why others language have special way to  handle this scenario?

Comment: @dnup1092: different languages have different limitations and tradeoffs.

Comment: thanks. Actually  just started learning python.Having a background of C++ and Java made me to think there should be some way. May be devs will consider to take the good things of others lang.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very contrived (and Considered Silly [tm]), and that is probably not what you want, but here's something you may look at just in case you really really want something like explicit nestable values.  I don't know for sure whether this constitutes "Assigning value to local variable then accessing the global variable".

Someone could possibly refine it to make it more like C++ or Java, or prove that it is impossible to have it like them.  But why ;)

```
class InNestedScope(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        if value is not None:
            self._value = value

    def getv(self):
        try:
            return self._value
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                return self.outer
            except NoOuterScopeError:
                raise AttributeError("No value found in this scope"
                                     " or the chain of enclosing scopes.")

    def setv(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def delv(self):
        del self._value

    value = property(getv, setv, delv,
                     "The actual attribute keeping the value.")

    @property
    def outer(self):
        if self.parent is None:
            raise NoOuterScopeError
        return self.parent.value

    def new(self, value=None):
        return InNestedScope(value, self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value


class NoOuterScopeError(Exception):
    pass


value = InNestedScope("GlobalString")


def func():
    global value
    value = value.new()
    print "value just after creation: %s " % value
    print ("it is%s the same as its global counterpart's" %
           ("" if value == globals()["value"] else " not"))
    print
    value.value = "LocalString"
    print "value just after explicit assignment: %s" % value
    print
    print "accessing global value from local value: %s " % value.outer
```

Interactive trial:

```
>>> func()
value just after creation: GlobalString
it is the same as its global counterpart's

value just after explicit assignment: LocalString

accessing global value from local value: GlobalString
```